# Comparação de index (get) em ArrayList não funcionando adequadamente

Tags: java, arraylist, switch, do-while, equals

Venho tentando fazer a comparação de uma *string* (resposta certa) para uma alternativa de uma questão como exemplo em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo, mas não consigo sucesso de todos os modos diferentes que tento.

O objetivo é que **a cada resposta errada** dada, **as alternativas são embaralhadas** e, enquanto a pessoa não responder a alternativa correta, o *loop* se repete.

As opções - *a, b, c, d, e* - se mantém intocáveis. Somente o texto das alternativas são embaralhadas. A questão é simples mas é de exemplificação.

Estou utilizando o `.get()` por meio do `for` que me retorna de 0 até 4 para cada elemento da `ArrayList`. É nesse momento que a comparação por meio do `switch` junto da variável `boolean` aparenta não dar certo, apesar do `Collections.shuffle` funcionar de maneira correta a cada tentativa errada. Por exemplo se eu testar fora do escopo do (*a,b,c,d,e*).

Segue o meu código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean acertou = false;
    List<String> questao = new ArrayList<String>();
    questao.add("Porta OR");
    questao.add("Porta XOR");
    questao.add("Porta AND");
    questao.add("Porta NOR");
    questao.add("Porta NOT");

    String opcaoCorreta = "Porta NOT", opcaoString;
    char opcao;

    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            questao.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println(
                "(Conceitos de Computação) Que porta lógica utilizamos para inverter o sinal lógico recebido?\n");
        System.out.println("a) " + questao.get(0));
        System.out.println("b) " + questao.get(1));
        System.out.println("c) " + questao.get(2));
        System.out.println("d) " + questao.get(3));
        System.out.println("e) " + questao.get(4));

        System.out.println("\nResposta: ");
        opcaoString = input.next();
        opcao = opcaoString.charAt(0);

        switch (opcao) {
        case 'a':
            if (opcaoCorreta.equals(questao.get(0))) {
                acertou = true;
            }
                break;
        case 'b':
            if (opcaoCorreta.equals(questao.get(1))) {
                acertou = true;
            }
                break;
        case 'c':
            if (opcaoCorreta.equals(questao.get(2))) {
                acertou = true;
            }
                break;
        case 'd':
            if (opcaoCorreta.equals(questao.get(3))) {
                acertou = true;
            }
                break;
        case 'e':
            if (opcaoCorreta.equals(questao.get(4))) {
                acertou = true;
            }
                break;
        if (acertou == true) {
            System.out.println("Resposta correta");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Resposta incorreta");
            Collections.shuffle(questao);
        }

    } while (!acertou);

    input.close();
} }
```

Utilização do `break` dentro do `if` em `switch-case` consistia o grande problema do código, este agora arrumado e funcionando com o equals.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos, logo após dar a aceitação).

Answer (score 1):

O código é um pouco complicado demais e até por isso tem erros.

A primeira coisa que fiz foi trocar o nome da variável que guarda as respostas porque é isso que ela é, ela não é uma questão. Eu trocaria por um *array* porque a quantidade de elementos não é variável, mas aí teria que criar uma função de `shuffle()` própria já que Java não tem uma pronta, e acho que não é sua hora ainda, ou fazer conversão, o que não faria sentido, então deixei assim.

Acessar as opções podem ser feitas por matemática evitar esse código todo. Note quantas variáveis eu eliminei, variável é complexidade.

Eu troquei o embaralhamento de lugar porque deveria fazer antes de começar e não faz sentido embaralhar de novo depois que a pessoa erra. Até poderia ter um enunciado dizendo isto, mas ele não foi postado na pergunta e mesmo que exista pede para fazer algo ilógico.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean acertou = false;
        List<String> respostas = new ArrayList<String>();
        respostas.add("Porta OR");
        respostas.add("Porta XOR");
        respostas.add("Porta AND");
        respostas.add("Porta NOR");
        respostas.add("Porta NOT");
        int opcaoCorreta = 4;
        Collections.shuffle(respostas);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("(Conceitos de Computação) Que porta lógica utilizamos para inverter o sinal lógico recebido?");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.println(((char)(i + 'a')) + ") " + respostas.get(i));
            System.out.println("Resposta: ");
            char opcao = input.next().charAt(0);
            if (opcao - 'a' == opcaoCorreta) {
                System.out.println("Resposta correta");
                break;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YpLslO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/RightAnswerjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Quiz.java).

Comment: Notei no seu código que ele já indexa 'automaticamente' a alternativa (a, b, c...) pertinente a cada questão, mas não consegui entender no for como foi feito isso. Poderia explicar? Grato pela paciência!

Comment: Usando matemática e conversão de tipo, acho o número na tabela ASCII e e o trato como caractere.